# second order partial derivative notation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

What is the reason for a second-order derivative notation to be:

$\frac{d^2y} {dx^2}$

and not:

$\frac{d^2y} {d^2x}$ or $\frac{dy^2} {dx^2}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think of it as applying $\frac d{dx}$ to $y$ twice; by the way, your title and tags say *partial* derivative, but the body of your question doesn't seem to go with that

Comment: If you want a partial derivative write `\partial`. The idea of where to put the exponents is the same for either kind of derivative, however, so perhaps asking about ordinary derivatives is enough, in which case you could just delete the word "partial" from the title.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(  \frac{d}{dx} \left(  y  \right)   \right)  =\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \left(   y \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: First of all, thank you  @David for the \partial tip I just learned a bit of MathJax for this question and why does the bottom d not have a power of two also, or is it implied that the power is for the whole dx and not just the x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to take the derivative of 
$\newcommand{d}{\mathrm d}f(x) = \left(e^x + \frac1x\right).$
You can write

$$ \frac\d{\d x} \left(e^x + \frac1x\right). $$

If you want the second derivative of $f(x)$, that's the derivative of the derivative:

$$ \frac\d{\d x} \left( \frac\d{\d x} \left(e^x + \frac1x\right)\right). $$

Now it's a notational convention that you can write $\d^2$ to combine the two $\d$ symbols in the "numerator" and $\d x^2$ to combine the two $\d x$ symbols in the "denominator".
But it's just a convention.

It might be a little clearer if we wrote $(\d x)^2$ instead of $\d x^2,$
but (again) it's just a notational convention anyway;
we are not really multiplying $\d x$ by $\d x.$

Answer (score -1):

The first derivation to any equation Let it be (y) is as follows:

d\dx (y)

When we take the second derivative of the function (y) , We must hit the first differential at :

(d\dx) * ( d\dx (y) )

Finally, the second derivative becomes the following :

( d^2\dx^2 (y) )

( d^2(Y)\dx^2 )

I wish God success .