# A question aboiut the second derivative and its notation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $y$ is a function of $x$. For the second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ we write:
$$ \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} $$
I am wondering why we do not write:
$$ \dfrac{dy^2}{dx^2} $$
or this:
$$ \dfrac{d^2y}{d^2x} $$

Is it simple a convention?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{d}{dx}[y]\right]$

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525107/second-order-partial-derivative-notation)